# Very simple calculator with four basic operations using only if/else statements

Tags: c#, beginner, console, calculator

I created a simple calculator with multiplication, division, addition, and subtraction. Is there a way to write it shorter? I am a beginner so I do not know much about programming other than if...else statements and different data types.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the simple calculator! The four operators of this calculator are +, -, *(multiply), and /(divide)");
        Console.Write("Number: ");
        string number = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Second Number: ");
        string secondNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Operator: ");
        string operatorType = Console.ReadLine();

        var numberConversion = Convert.ToInt64(number);
        var secondNumberConversion = Convert.ToInt64(secondNumber);
        var sum = numberConversion + secondNumberConversion; //Result of addition
        var difference = numberConversion - secondNumberConversion; //Result of subtraction
        var product = numberConversion * secondNumberConversion; //Result of multiplication
        var quotient = numberConversion / secondNumberConversion; //Result of division

        if (operatorType == "+")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        } else if (operatorType == "-")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(difference);
        } else if (operatorType == "*")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(product);
        } else if (operatorType == "/")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(quotient);
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the correct operator");
        }
```

Comment: I suggest moving the calculation inside the `if`/`elseif` tree, otherwise you may find that `2 + 0` causes a divide-by-zero error.

Comment: Or [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)  :)

Comment: instead of convert.toint, use the tryparse method and handle exceptions if you have learned about them yet or getting to that lesson at some point.  You want to be able to handle an error prone user typing in + + +..

Comment: Nice question. However, you should include your whole program (including the `static void Main()` method signature).

Comment: You need to understand that quality has usually nothing to do with how long your code is but how extensible and stable. But, of course, beginners tend to do many things in a roundabout and overly wordy way..

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to check for input validity and have a mechanism for retry. Users can enter all sorts of things
2. Your variable names aren't consistent. `number` and `secondNumber`. I would go with `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` in your scheme, but I would not use your scheme.
3. Your variable names are too verbose: `secondNumberConversion`. How about `n1` and `n2`?
4. A simple, elegant, maintainable and extensible solution is to use a Dictionary.

Not addressing 1. here is my version:

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the simple calculator!"
                  + " The four operators of this calculator are "
                  + "+, -, *(multiply), and /(divide)");

Console.Write("First Number: ");
Int64 n1 = Int64.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Second Number: ");
Int64 n2 = Int64.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Operator: ");
string operatorType = Console.ReadLine();

var operatorsFuncMap = new Dictionary<string, Func<Int64, Int64, Int64>> 
{
    {"+", (a, b) => a + b},
    {"-", (a, b) => a - b},
    {"*", (a, b) => a * b},
    {"/", (a, b) => a / b},
};

Console.WriteLine(operatorsFuncMap[operatorType](n1, n2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the simple calculator! The four operators of this calculator are +, -, *(multiply), and /(divide)");
        Console.Write("Number: ");
        string number = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Second Number: ");
        string secondNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Operator: ");
        string operatorType = Console.ReadLine();

        var numberConversion = Convert.ToInt64(number);
        var secondNumberConversion = Convert.ToInt64(secondNumber);

        switch (operatorType)
        {
            case "+":
                Console.WriteLine(numberConversion + secondNumberConversion);
                break;
            case "-":
                Console.WriteLine(numberConversion - secondNumberConversion);
                break;
            case "*":
                Console.WriteLine(numberConversion * secondNumberConversion);
                break;
            case "/":
                Console.WriteLine(numberConversion / secondNumberConversion);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the correct operator");
                break;
        }
```

More info here on `switch`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

I prefer using `switch` over a long `If Then` just because it's easier to read.